# AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'upper'

Tags: python

I wrote this code to use the Pythagorean theorem but I get the error shown below when I execute the code.

Why am I getting an `AttributeError` here?

```
import math
while True:

    missing_value_valid = False
    while missing_value_valid == False:
        try:
            missing_value_text = input('Please enter the missing side: ')
            missing_value_valid = True
        except ValueError:
            print ('Please enter a valid variable.')

        missing_value = missing_value_text

        if missing_value.upper() == 'C':
            print ('please enter the known lengths: ')
            adjacent_side = int(input('please enter the length of the adjacent side:'))
            opposite_side = int(input('please enter the length of the opposite side:'))
            hypotenuse = math.pow(adjacent_side,2) + math.pow(opposite_side,2)
            missing_value =  math.sqrt(abs(float(hypotenuse)))
            print('The answer is:', (float(missing_value)))

        if missing_value.upper() == 'B':
            print ('please enter the known lengths: ') 
            adjacent_side = int(input('Please enter the lenght of the adjacent side:'))
            hypotenuse = int(input('Please enter the lenght of the hypotenuse side:'))
            opposite_side = math.pow(adjacent_side,2) - math.pow(hypotenuse,2)
            missing_value =  math.sqrt(abs(float(opposite_side)))
            print('the answer is:', (float(missing_value)))

        if missing_value.upper() == 'A':
            print ('please enter the known lengths: ') 
            opposite_side = int(input('Please enter the lenght of the adjacent side: '))
            hypotenuse = int(input('Please enter the lenght of the hypotenuse side: '))
            adjacent_side = math.pow(opposite_side,2) - math.pow(hypotenuse,2)
            missing_value =  math.sqrt(abs(float(adjacent_side)))
            print('The answer is: ', (float(missing_value)))
```

Full error:

```
Exception has occurred: AttributeError
'float' object has no attribute 'upper'
  File "C:\Users\kiran\Documents\python files\pythogerous theorem\pythegrous theorem.py", line 22, in <module>
    if missing_value.upper() == 'B':
```

I only get this error when I check the code for the value for C.

Comment: it looks like this is homework. see [asking about homework](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/334823/6619250)
to ask good homework questions.

Comment: I had this same issues in one of the 12 data basses am checking. Some how the ID column that pandas picked up as an Object, there was a float somewhere in there. so i did the following column['ID'] = column['ID'].astype('str")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you change the value of `missing_value` by setting it to `math.sqrt(abs(float(hypotenuse)))`...

```py
if missing_value.upper() == 'C':
    # ...
    missing_value =  math.sqrt(abs(float(hypotenuse)))
    print('The answer is:', (float(missing_value)))
```

and here you try to compare that variable (now a `float`) to `B`:

```py
if missing_value.upper() == 'B':
```

`float`s don't have an `upper()` method, as the error message suggests.

You probably want to use `elif` instead of `if` for the `B` and `A` branches so the only run if the previous clauses are false.